# Changing md-subheader-inner css property

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to remove the padding:16px; property the md-subheader-inner inherits from the md-subheader directive.

The problem is, that when applying another class on my subheader, it seems like i can't change the inner style properties. I have made a codepen trying to show what the problem is [here](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/jxmKOR?editors=1111).

Whenever I inspect the element, it doesn't matter which of the two solution I made, the css properties are not updated... I think I am missing something obvious here, but I can't figure out what this is.

Please note that I don't want to use direct modification on md-subheader class because I am using that directive on a lot of places and I don't want any side effect (hence my 'padding-less-inner' class).

**Html**:

```
<md-select name="test" multiple="true" ng-model="whatever">
<md-subheader class="md-sticky padding-less-inner">
  <md-input-container style="width:100%;padding-left:8px;padding-right: 24px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <input style="width: calc(100% - 30px);float: right;" ng-model="searchText" class="_md-text" onkeydown="stopPropagation(event)">
  </md-input-container>
</md-subheader>
<md-optgroup>
  <md-option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in querySearch()">{{item.name_fr}}</md-option>
</md-optgroup>
```

**CSS**:

```
.padding-less-inner {
    .md-subheader-inner {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    /*div {
         padding: 0 !important;        
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight modification to your CSS:

```css
.padding-less-inner .md-subheader-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```